# Push Twitter Data through spark in AWS Kinesis Firehose using Scala

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, twitter

I use this scala code to push data in Kenisis

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.{AWSStaticCredentialsProvider, DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain}

object TestPush {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClientBuilder
    import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordsRequest
    import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordsRequestEntry
    import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordsResult
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer
    import java.util

    val credentials = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
    val kinesisClient = AmazonKinesisClientBuilder.standard()
      .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials.getCredentials))
      .withRegion("eu-west-1").build()

    val putRecordsRequest = new PutRecordsRequest
    putRecordsRequest.setStreamName("episen-ds1")
    val putRecordsRequestEntryList = new util.ArrayList[PutRecordsRequestEntry]
    for (i <- 0 until 100) {
      val myString : String = "Tony"+i+";"+i+"\n"
      val putRecordsRequestEntry = new PutRecordsRequestEntry
      putRecordsRequestEntry.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(myString.getBytes))
      putRecordsRequestEntry.setPartitionKey(String.format("test"))
      putRecordsRequestEntryList.add(putRecordsRequestEntry)
    }

    putRecordsRequest.setRecords(putRecordsRequestEntryList)
    val putRecordsResult: PutRecordsResult = kinesisClient.putRecords(putRecordsRequest)
    System.out.println("Put Result" + putRecordsResult)
  }
}
```

This is scala code to pull data from Twitter

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    
    //Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    val twitterCredentials = new Array[String](4);
    //consumerKey
    twitterCredentials(0) = "";
    //consumerSecret
    twitterCredentials(1) = "";

    //accessToken
    twitterCredentials(2) =  "";
    //accessTokenSecret
    twitterCredentials(3) = "";

    val appName = "TweeterStream"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("local[2]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))
    val Array(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret) = twitterCredentials.take(4)

    val filters = args.takeRight(args.length - 4)

    val cb = new ConfigurationBuilder
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
      .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret)
    val auth = new OAuthAuthorization(cb.build)

    val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Some(auth), filters)
    val englishTweets = tweets.filter(_.getLang() == "en")
    englishTweets.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }
```

Build.sbt

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
    
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-kinesis" % "1.11.880"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core" % "1.11.880"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-kinesis" % "1.11.880"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core" % "1.11.880"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.3.2"
   
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.6.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.1.0"
)
```

How can I mix them to have one code in which pulls data from Twitter and pushes it into kenisis? In order to be able to execute SQL queries on this data.

In the first code I send a string to kenisis which is very simple but I don't know how to transfer twitters to string to send it to kenisis.

How can I make this work?

Comment: you might want to add your build.sbt file

Comment: i did it, i changed the post

Comment: `spark-mllib_2.10`? but `scalaVersion := "2.11.11"`

Comment: i can change the version no probleme , my probleme is how to mix codes

Comment: Off the top of my head I'd try and create a create `PutRecordsRequestEntry` for each tweet... sort of looping over the `DStream`. Something along these lines: https://gist.github.com/mfirry/6ebe6599df2ba9b96ca13edfcbd4a1b1

Comment: code running but kenisis is empty ( no data saved)

Comment: I've updated the gist. Check it out. Keep in mind this might not be the BEST and recommended way to do this. You should learn about Spark Streaming a bit.

Comment: also nothing is working :(

Comment: You have nested RDD? does Spark   allow to use  nest rdd ?